# Wheelnav adding OnMouseDown event to Spreader

Tags: wheelnav.js

My donut chart works excellent I am using the wheel nav but I can't seem to find anywhere in the docs info on onmousedown for the spreader. When the spreader is in I'd like to add a pop up on mousedown. Any ideas?

I tried to use an on clock method but that didn't seem to work. Great library but very little info on how to manipulate it without changing the entire source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your needs via onmouseup event:

```
  var wheel = new wheelnav("wheelDiv");
  wheel.spreaderEnable = true;
  wheel.createWheel(["This", "is", "custom", "spreader"]);

  var wheelspreader = document.getElementById("wheelnav-wheelDiv-spreader");
  var wheelspreadertitle = document.getElementById("wheelnav-wheelDiv-spreadertitle");
  wheelspreader.onmouseup = function() {alert("spread it!");}
  wheelspreadertitle.onmouseup = function() {alert("spread it!");}
```

Here is a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/sarosoh/edit?html,js,output) sample.